# How to list down Android phone settings menu items in my application?

Tags: android, settings

I wanted to list down android phone settings with in application.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of settings you need to list down??

There are many settings, and Android SDK provide the APIs to access there status.

For example, if you require to get the volume settings you may use AudioManager etc ...

**Edit**

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

int maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); // also get for diffrent streams here

System.out.println(maxVolume);
```

Comment: I hope, with this audiomanager objecct we could change the audio settings, but I wanted to list down all the sound settings how they listed down in the device. for ex if select sound settings option in the mobile,It will list down all types of sound settings, I exactly want this to be listed down in my application list activity as it is in the mobile sound settings menu. fyi: android 2.2 - motorala device